# Bash wildcards repeated match

Tags: bash, wildcards

Can bash list with a repeated string? Lets say I wanted to match the files

```
config_foo_foo.txt
config_bar_bar.txt
```

but NOT

```
config_foo_bar.txt
```

something like

```
ls -l config_*_*.txt
```

matches all three. Would I have to use something like grep and a regular expression to get the behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott's answer looks right. With find it looks like this:

1.

```
find * -maxdepth 0 -regex "^config_\(.*\)_\1\.txt$"
```

Output:

```
config_foo_foo.txt
config_bar_bar.txt
```

2.

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -regex "^\./config_\(.*\)_\1\.txt$"
```

Output:

```
./config_foo_foo.txt
./config_bar_bar.txt
```

Comment: Wouldn’t `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` be better than `find * -maxdepth 0`?

Comment: Ah yes thanks. I figured regex would be the solution since I couldn't find anything for bash to do it. Find is better than getting all of them then filtering with grep like I was thinking.

Comment: @Scott fixed...

Comment: @Scott  find .  would give you "./" at the beginning of each line...

Comment: @Radoo: “`find .` would give you `./` at the beginning of each line.”  OK, true.  So what?

Comment: @Scott It's just not what f4hy wanted. You don't need to do extra text processing when there's an easy way to skip this action. "Less is more."

Comment: @Radoo: “It’s just not what f4hy wanted.”  What’s your basis for saying that? From the question, it is reasonable to believe that he just wants to _access_ the files whose names match `config_\(.*\)_\1\.txt`.  If that’s all he wants, the `./` doesn’t matter.

Comment: @Radoo: “You don't need to do extra text processing when there's an easy way to skip this action.  "Less is more."”  What “extra text processing”?  Do you mean extra typing?  Skip what action?

Comment: @Radoo: _You_ said, “Find is faster for large number[s] of files.”  My point is: if you say `find .`, then `find` reads `.` (the current directory) and lists the names it finds.  With `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` and no inode-referencing predicate, it shouldn’t need to `stat` the files.  Whereas, if you say `find *`, ***the shell*** reads the current directory ***AND SORTS IT***, then invokes `find` with the sorted list of directory entries.  Even with `-maxdepth 0`, `find` is probably going to `stat` each one to verify that it exists.  See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12659).

Comment: @Scott I thought he wanted to just have the file names without any ./ at the beginning, that's how I interpreted the question. You're right about the . vs *, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try the following code (using extented `glob`s ) :

```
shopt -s extglob
ls config_!(*foo_bar*).txt
```

See

- `man bash | less +/shopt.*optname`
- http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob

Comment: Oh that is fine for my example but wont match generic wild cards. It will just exclude anything with the string "foo_bar" but wont exclude bar_foo or baz_bar etc. I want any possible repeated string to be matched. I don't see how to do that with extglob but that is what I am asking.

Comment: I was going to suggest `config+(_*).txt`, but that matches one or more of any `_*`, not one or more of the first thing that matches `_*`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may need to do something like

```
command $(ls -d config_*_*.txt | grep '^config_\(.*\)_\1\.txt$')
```